# Is it safe to mark library functions that modify the calling contract's state as public in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, visibility, libraries

I am using libraries to reduce the cost of deployment of a contract of which there may be many instances (using a factory contract). When I mark a library function as internal, the code seems to get inlined into the calling contract, which for me defeats the purpose of using a library. My question is, is it safe to mark library functions that modify the calling contract's state as public, even though they are only intended to be called from within the contract?

According to solidity docs:

> Library functions can only be called directly (i.e. without the use of `DELEGATECALL`) if they do not modify the state (i.e. if they are `view` or `pure` functions), because libraries are assumed to be stateless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe. The fragment you're citing refers to calling library functions using an ordinary external `CALL` instead of the typical `DELEGATECALL`. At the EVM level there's no difference between a contract and a library. Each is just a piece of bytecode at a particular address and has its own, isolated storage space. When a contract `DELEGATECALL`s a library, it gives it access to its storage space, which covers the original space of the library and makes that space inaccessible. If the contract `CALL`ed it instead, the library would have access to its own storage space and any changes made there would be "lost" to the contract. They'd still be preserved in storage, just not the storage belonging to the contract.

This is only a problem if you actually let the library read/write is own storage space. `DELEGATECALL` prevents that so it's always safe in that sense. It's also save to `CALL` a `pure` function as such functions cannot access storage at all.

`view` functions on the other hand might be affected if they accept `storage` arguments and try to read them. That's because a `storage` argument is just a reference to some place in contract's storage and in case of a `CALL` the library does not have access to that storage. The call is still "safe" though in the sense that there won't be any lost state modifications.

So, to summarize, it would only be unsafe if your intention was to have the contract use `CALL` to call these functions. You don't have to worry about that happening if you only use the high-level call syntax (i.e. `L.foo(x, y, z)`). You'd have to use the low-level `address.call()` function or inline assembly to get into this problem.